# How to write regular expression - contain substrings and not contain other substring

Tags: regex, expression

I nedd to check:
1) string contains "Canal" "Film"
2) string not contains "HD"

```
Canal+ Film 2 HD
Canal+ Film 2
```

This will check that string contains all substrings:

```
(?=.*Canal)(?=.*Film)
```

How to add to this regex pattern not contains condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^(?=.*Canal)(?=.*Film)(?!.*HD)
```

Comment: I added an anchor, otherwise a string like `"HD Canal Film"` would match.

Comment: Ehh.. Thanks :). I forgot I can use this like that. Regex rules!

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/rM7mB1  it seems to working without ^ also (I've changed regex tester link)

Comment: @oobe: You're forgetting the `.*` before `HD`. But there seems to be an error in regex101, because http://regex101.com/r/tO2uC1 *should*  match (and if you test it in PHP, you'll see it will). It seems that zero-length matches aren't always tested at all positions of the string...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker it's ok... channel "HD Canal Film" should not match.. (?!.*HD) I notice that too (.*).. thx! http://regex101.com/r/nK6nE4

Comment: @oobe: Misunderstanding there. I know it should not match, and regex101.com says that it won't, but if you try it outside of regex101, you'll see that it *will*  match.

Comment: In C# regex is correct result.. later I'll try in python